# Whole LAN cannot access internet after we renewed SSL on SBS 2011 Server

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I am rapidly looking for solution to mess at my client. They have LAN network with some 50 computers and their main server is Windows Server 2008R2 under SBS 2011. They needed paid SSL renewal and we did it, using MultiDomain SSL with 4 Alternate DN, so to cover all SBS needs (autodiscover, mail, remote, www).
But previous SSL was SHA1 with SHA1 root, and new one is SHA2 with full SHA2 root. And SBS 2011 has problems with it, because it was screaming and fighting against it, but finally with all ROOT and INTERMEDIATE certs, with some help of Exchange PowerShell we did it. All working well.

BUT PROBLEM
During the 5-hours SSL install process we obviously messed up with some deep Windows authentication mechanism, because now **none of LAN computers can access internet**. Neither with FireFox, Chrome nor IE, any version, any OS, Windows 7 or Windows 10 - nobody can access any web page, neither HTTP nor HTTPS.
Errors are "Connection lost", "The page cannot be displayed" and such.

No proxy is in use.

BUT I can Ping "www.google.com" and I get proper IP.

```
Pinging www.google.com [216.58.211.132] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.211.132: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=53
Reply from 216.58.211.132: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=53
```

AND all Outlooks work fine (with internal Exchange), mail goes out and in, no problem.

Just no internet/web for anyone.
**EDIT: Seems like just no HTTP access! But HTTPS sites are accessible.**
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just like the problem being weird and never-heard-of, like was the solution: rebooting both SBS and the other local DNS server, alongside with router/firewall solved the problem.
I guess there was a conflict on TCP/IP encryption layer, either on DNS or more likely on firewall/router.